# Doctrine get non null ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to get all Entity only if the parameter is part in this entity or if the entity parameter is empty.

I have this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cc')                
->join('Toblor\Entity\Paramount', 'p')
->select('p')
->Where(':company MEMBER OF p.company_activated')
->setParameter('company ', $company)

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And it is doing to job great. But now I would like to have the same result if company is a part of company_actived OR if company_activated is empty. I have tried an

```
->Where('(:company MEMBER OF p.company_activated OR p.company_activated IS NULL)')
```

It trigger me this error

```
Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

Is there an easy way to do this thing ? Because I need to implement on a lot of fields.

Thanks you

Comment: did you tried to add a `orWhere` condition instead of mixing the 2 conditions in the same `where`?

Comment: Yes but I dont want to interfer with the rest of the query (which is pretty big)

Comment: And with a `$qb->expr()->orX`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your relation with `company_activated` `ManyToMany` or `OneToMany`.

If it's the case, you need to add:

```
->leftJoin('p.company_activated', 'ca')
```

then check if `ca IS NULL`